# Get cpu of child process

Tags: c, linux, child-process

I am writing a program that launches several child processes through fork() and needs to periodically track which CPU they are on. Is there any way to accomplish this in C?

I am aware of cpu_getaffinity(), but that's within the process itself. I would like to be able to call a function that would let me know what CPU a child process is running on based on the PID, and I haven't been able to find anything quite related to that.

The closest I've found is to access the /proc/ filesystem, but is there a way to do it within the program and not looking through an external system?

Comment: "what CPU a child process is running on". Could be many CPUs at once, or none at all. Why? "looking through an external system". /proc is not external. It's a kernel interface, not really different from any old syscall.

Comment: You can have each child process check itself, then report back to the parent via shared memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check it in parent process through /proc interface
2. check it in child processes, and send it back to parent process through IPC, such as shared memory or socket, etc..